# Cocos2d-x V3.2. Create sprite with RenderTexture

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have a problem.

i'm trying to make a screenshot of a scene then make a sprite and pass this sprite to other scene.
i'm doing this:

```
RenderTexture* texture = RenderTexture::create((int)Director::getInstance()->getWinSize().width, (int)Director::getInstance()->getWinSize().height, Texture2D::PixelFormat::RGBA8888);
texture->begin();
Director::getInstance()->getRunningScene()->visit();
texture->end();
Sprite* bgSprite = Sprite::createWithTexture(texture->getSprite()->getTexture());
bgSprite->setRotationX(180);
/-------------------------------------
LoadScreen* loadLayer = LoadScreen::create(GameScene, this->_carModel, bgSprite/*, this*/);
/-------------------------------------
```

then in next scene i do:

```
bgSprite->setPosition(Point(Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize().width / 2, Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize().height / 2));
bgSprite->setOpacity(200);
this->addChild(bgSprite, 1, 1);
```

I debug this. Sprite is not null. The texture in this sprite has size and etc.
I try to save texure in file. The result is empty .png file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an engine problem, the file is alway saved with RGB in the previous version.

Since the rendering of cocos2d-x 3.0 is based on the command queue, we should always wrap the read/write frame buffer operations with commands. Invoking newImage() directly is not guaranteed to work fine. But "RenderTexture::saveToFile" should work fine because it's wrapped with a custom command in code.

I think this issue has already been solved in cocos2d-x v3.3, please refer http://www.cocos2d-x.org/issues/5562 for more information.

And also you could take a look at "cpp-tests" bundled with cocos2d-x to see how to save screenshot of your scene or sprite.